# Setting the top and margin of divs to zero

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2 divs inside a div, and I want the 2 divs to be 0px away from the top of the parent container, and also for them to have no margins around them.

I tried setting the position of the 2 divs to relative, and top to 0px, and the margin to 0px, but it doesn't set them for some reason.

```css
#firstOuter {
  border: 1px solid orange;
}
.outer {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="firstOuter">

  <div class="outer">
    <div>
      one
    </div>
    <div>
      two
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="outer">
    <div>
      one
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`display:inline-block` is quite tricky. It accounts spaces as elements are treated as inline blocks. You should a) remove spaces and b) set vertical alignment properly.

```css
#firstOuter {
  border: 1px solid orange;
}
.outer {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  vertical-align:top; 
}
```

```html
<div id="firstOuter"><div class="outer">
    <div>
      one
    </div>
    <div>
      two
    </div>
  </div><div class="outer">
    <div>
      one
    </div>
  </div></div>
```

Comment: the problem shown solved here, but when using other browser it still shows a little gap between the two divs. I used firefox 41.0 for testing.

Comment: @SandipanGuha If you set the body font to 0, and then set font size on #firstOuter, maybe it fixes it?

Comment: I do not see any problems in FF with that code. Could share screenshot?

Comment: _Screenshots:_

**Firefox 41.0**: [link](http://prntscr.com/8pkdjb)


**IE 11.0**: [link](http://prntscr.com/8pkfs6)


**Chrome 45.0**: [link](http://prntscr.com/8pkh5r)

Comment: I don't know @frosty. I tried the upper code and only `float:left` fixes the problem!

Comment: @SandipanGuha You have to remove spaces from your samples. New lines are also spaces for the HTML as you know.

Answer (score 1):

you can add `vertical-align:top;` to your `.outer` css,

```
.outer {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

---

then add comment to your div to Remove the spaces

```
</div><!--
--><div class="outer">
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ve0d8Lfq/)**

or just remove the space between `divs`

```
</div><div class="outer">
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ve0d8Lfq/3/)**

Answer (score -2):

Floating you outer divs is the first part of the solution. Then you need to self clear the parent container so that div wraps around as intended.

https://jsfiddle.net/partypete25/5r06zjm3/

```
#firstOuter {
  border: 1px solid orange;
}
#firstOuter:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.outer {
  float:left;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Why `float:left;` together with `display: inline-block;` ? What's the purpose/intent?

Comment: Yeah you're right, i shouldn't have specified display as inline-block. Just remove it and maintain the float:left. The main difference between the two, other than vertical-alignment, is that floats are more forgiving when it comes to accidental blank/empty spaces between your elements.

Comment: Check  "overuse of flooats considered harmful" of one of Mozilla creators: http://dbaron.org/log/2005-12, there are flexboxes for that purpose too.

Comment: `float` does push the edges of margin to another element but `display: inline-block` makes it nice and cozy, that's why in this problem `display: inline-block` doesn't resolve the problem but `float: left` does. when using, `float: left` and `vertical-align: top` together makes the proper solution of this problem.